# OpenMPI Installation on Archlinux

Tags: archlinux, openmpi

Hi I have the following installations on archlinux:

server:

```
sudo pacman -S openmpi
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
chmod 600 authorized_key
sssh-copy-id miniserver
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Add the following lines
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    RSAAuthentication yes
sudo pacman -S ntp
sudo vi /etc/ntp.conf: Add the following lines
server 0.arch.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.arch.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.arch.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.arch.pool.ntp.org iburst
    tos orphan 15
    logfile /var/log/ntp.log
sudo ntpd -u ntp:ntp
sudo systemctl start ntpd.service
sudo systemctl enable ntpd.service
sudo pacman -S nfs-utils
mkdir ~/sharedfolder
chmod 777 ~/sharedfolder
sudo vi /etc/exports:
    /home/vorlket/sharedfolder      miniserver(rw,sync)
sudo exportfs -arv
sudo systemctl start nfs-server.service
sudo systemctl enable nfs-server.service
```

miniserver:

```
sudo pacman -S openmpi
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys
chmod 600 authorized_key
sssh-copy-id server
sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config:
    PubkeyAuthentication yes
    RSAAuthentication yes
sudo pacman -S ntp
sudo vi /etc/ntp.conf: Add the following lines
    server 192.168.1.3
sudo systemctl start ntpd.service
sudo systemctl enable ntpd.service
sudo pacman -S nfs-utils
mkdir ~/sharedfolder
chmod 777 ~/sharedfolder
sudo vi /etc/fstab:
    server:/home/vorlket/sharedfolder       /home/vorlket/sharedfolder      nfs _netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=10,timeo=14,x-systemd.idle-timeout=1min 0 0
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
```

I tried to run the following and got an error:

```
[vorlket@server ~]$ mpirun -host server,miniserver -np 4 /home/vorlket/sharedfolder/mpi-prime
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ORTE was unable to reliably start one or more daemons.
This usually is caused by:

* not finding the required libraries and/or binaries on
  one or more nodes. Please check your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  settings, or configure OMPI with --enable-orterun-prefix-by-default

* lack of authority to execute on one or more specified nodes.
  Please verify your allocation and authorities.

* the inability to write startup files into /tmp (--tmpdir/orte_tmpdir_base).
  Please check with your sys admin to determine the correct location to use.

*  compilation of the orted with dynamic libraries when static are required
  (e.g., on Cray). Please check your configure cmd line and consider using
  one of the contrib/platform definitions for your system type.

* an inability to create a connection back to mpirun due to a
  lack of common network interfaces and/or no route found between
  them. Please check network connectivity (including firewalls
  and network routing requirements).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

mpi-prime.c:

```
[vorlket@server ~]$ cat /home/vorlket/mpiprac/mpi-prime.c
# include <math.h>
# include <mpi.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] );
int prime_number ( int n, int id, int p );
void timestamp ( );

/******************************************************************************/

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )

/******************************************************************************/
/*
  Purpose:

    MAIN is the main program for PRIME_MPI.

  Discussion:

    This program calls a version of PRIME_NUMBER that includes
    MPI calls for parallel processing.

  Licensing:

    This code is distributed under the GNU LGPL license.

  Modified:

    07 August 2009

  Author:

    John Burkardt
*/
{
  int i;
  int id;
  int ierr;
  int n;
  int n_factor;
  int n_hi;
  int n_lo;
  int p;
  int primes;
  int primes_part;
  double wtime;

  n_lo = 1;
  n_hi = 1048576;
  n_factor = 2;
/*
  Initialize MPI.
*/
  ierr = MPI_Init ( &argc, &argv );
/*
  Get the number of processes.
*/
  ierr = MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &p );
/*
  Determine this processes's rank.
*/
  ierr = MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id );

  if ( id == 0 )
  {
    timestamp ( );
    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "PRIME_MPI\n" );
    printf ( "  C/MPI version\n" );
    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "  An MPI example program to count the number of primes.\n" );
    printf ( "  The number of processes is %d\n", p );
    printf ( "\n" );
    printf ( "         N        Pi          Time\n" );
    printf ( "\n" );
  }

  n = n_lo;

  while ( n <= n_hi )
  {
    if ( id == 0 )
    {
      wtime = MPI_Wtime ( );
    }
    ierr = MPI_Bcast ( &n, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

    primes_part = prime_number ( n, id, p );

    ierr = MPI_Reduce ( &primes_part, &primes, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0,
      MPI_COMM_WORLD );

    if ( id == 0 )
    {
      wtime = MPI_Wtime ( ) - wtime;
      printf ( "  %8d  %8d  %14f\n", n, primes, wtime );
    }
    n = n * n_factor;
  }
/*
  Terminate MPI.
*/
  ierr = MPI_Finalize ( );
/*
  Terminate.
*/
  if ( id == 0 )
  {
    printf ( "\n");
    printf ( "PRIME_MPI - Master process:\n");
    printf ( "  Normal end of execution.\n");
    printf ( "\n" );
    timestamp ( );
  }

  return 0;
}
/******************************************************************************/

int prime_number ( int n, int id, int p )

/******************************************************************************/
/*
  Purpose:

    PRIME_NUMBER returns the number of primes between 1 and N.

  Discussion:

    In order to divide the work up evenly among P processors, processor
    ID starts at 2+ID and skips by P.

    A naive algorithm is used.

    Mathematica can return the number of primes less than or equal to N
    by the command PrimePi[N].

                N  PRIME_NUMBER

                1           0
               10           4
              100          25
            1,000         168
           10,000       1,229
          100,000       9,592
        1,000,000      78,498
       10,000,000     664,579
      100,000,000   5,761,455
    1,000,000,000  50,847,534

  Licensing:

    This code is distributed under the GNU LGPL license.

  Modified:

    21 May 2009

  Author:

    John Burkardt

  Parameters:

    Input, int N, the maximum number to check.

    Input, int ID, the ID of this process,
    between 0 and P-1.

    Input, int P, the number of processes.

    Output, int PRIME_NUMBER, the number of prime numbers up to N.
*/
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int prime;
  int total;

  total = 0;

  for ( i = 2 + id; i <= n; i = i + p )
  {
    prime = 1;
    for ( j = 2; j < i; j++ )
    {
      if ( ( i % j ) == 0 )
      {
        prime = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
    total = total + prime;
  }
  return total;
}
/******************************************************************************/

void timestamp ( void )

/******************************************************************************/
/*
  Purpose:

    TIMESTAMP prints the current YMDHMS date as a time stamp.

  Example:

    31 May 2001 09:45:54 AM

  Licensing:

    This code is distributed under the GNU LGPL license.

  Modified:

    24 September 2003

  Author:

    John Burkardt

  Parameters:

    None
*/
{
# define TIME_SIZE 40

  static char time_buffer[TIME_SIZE];
  const struct tm *tm;
  size_t len;
  time_t now;

  now = time ( NULL );
  tm = localtime ( &now );

  len = strftime ( time_buffer, TIME_SIZE, "%d %B %Y %I:%M:%S %p", tm );

  printf ( "%s\n", time_buffer );

  return;
# undef TIME_SIZE
}
```

What have I missed and/or done wrong here? I have run out of idea on what can be possible problems. The compiled program (with mpicc) on the sharedfolder runs ok on each individual machine.

Thanks for help in advance.